# My draw method doesn't draw the height

Tags: c#

I have a draw method that should draw out a box, but my problem is that it only draws out the width of the box, not the height.

Here's a code snippet:

```
class ColoredBox : Box
{
    protected ConsoleColor backColor;

    public ColoredBox(Point p, int width, int height, ConsoleColor backColor)
        : base(p, width, height)

    {
        this.backColor = backColor;
    }

    public virtual void Draw()
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(p.X, p.Y);
            Console.BackgroundColor = backColor;
            for (int i = 0; i <= width; i++)
                Console.Write(' ');
    }
}
```

The issue seem to be the `Draw()` method and that I can't print it out, so how can I fix this simple issue?

Comment: You do not break to a new line after the last `for` loop.

Comment: http://i45.tinypic.com/6h2fk2.jpg My printscreen result. It doesnt draw out the Width, the algoritm is incorrect somehow.

Comment: should be `SetCursorPosition(p.Y + j)`

Comment: @Aphelion which means that ? Can you show the example of the error so that I understood what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `j` when setting the cursor position for the next row. The code should read:

```
public virtual void Draw()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(p.X, p.Y + j);
        Console.BackgroundColor = backColor;
        for (int i = 0; i <= width; i++)
            Console.Write(' ');
    }
}
```